# Chaincode Instantiate is failed with Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

**Problem:**

I have created a Hyperledger fabric network with six organization and 2 peers for each and also 6 separate ca for organizations. It contains one orderer. I up the network and Install the chaincode successfully. But when I try to instantiate It with this command

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -n fabcar -l node -v 1.0  -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -C mychannel -P "AND ('Org2MSP.peer','Org3MSP.peer')"
```

It failed with leaving this error on the terminal.

```
2019-04-24 07:37:38.385 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2019-04-24 07:37:38.386 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
Instantiate chaincode Failed....
```

This is the logs of orderer.

```
2019-04-29 09:53:06.146 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 024 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.9:52658 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer0.org1.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=44.122382s
2019-04-29 09:53:18.915 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 025 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.16:41582 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer0.org4.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=43.0664988s
2019-04-29 09:53:22.614 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 026 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.8:45086 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org6.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=32.7623066s
2019-04-29 09:53:26.625 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 027 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.12:51754 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer0.org5.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=44.9992331s
2019-04-29 09:54:34.939 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 028 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.5:53352 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org3.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=2m1.9971354s
2019-04-29 09:56:51.205 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 029 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.9:32878
2019-04-29 09:56:51.359 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 02a TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.5:33586
2019-04-29 09:56:51.865 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 02b TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.8:53384
2019-04-29 09:56:51.712 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 02c TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.9:32812: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.9:32812
2019-04-29 09:56:51.372 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 02d TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.8:53304: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.8:53304
2019-04-29 10:01:35.755 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 02e TLS handshake failed with error read tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.9:40288: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.9:40288
2019-04-29 10:01:39.167 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 030 TLS handshake failed with error read tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.9:40376: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.9:40376
2019-04-29 10:01:39.411 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 031 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.18:50786 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer0.org2.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=9m25.7650582s
2019-04-29 10:01:40.914 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 032 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.18:41164
2019-04-29 10:01:39.167 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 02f streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.15:34396 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org4.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=9m0.2938332s
2019-04-29 10:01:41.548 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 033 TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.18:40902: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.18:40902
2019-04-29 10:01:41.696 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 034 Error reading from 172.18.0.21:52002: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-04-29 10:01:41.696 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 035 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.21:52002 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=7m31.7608952s
2019-04-29 10:01:40.914 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 036 TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.9:42114: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.9:42114
2019-04-29 10:01:41.168 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 037 TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.9:40842: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.9:40842
2019-04-29 10:01:43.005 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 038 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.9:32942 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer0.org1.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=4m49.156365s
2019-04-29 10:01:49.736 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 039 TLS handshake failed with error read tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.21:39106: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.21:39106
2019-04-29 10:01:55.321 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 03a TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.12:43194
2019-04-29 10:02:26.574 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 03b streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.10:51958 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org5.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=9m44.20611s
2019-04-29 10:02:41.074 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 03c TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.12:45900
2019-04-29 10:02:50.555 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 03d streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.8:53460 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org6.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=5m56.6333492s
2019-04-29 10:03:35.057 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 03e TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.12:47740: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.12:47740
2019-04-29 10:04:27.772 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 03f TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.16:41734
2019-04-29 10:04:48.830 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 040 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.16:43084
2019-04-29 10:04:50.666 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 041 TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.12:53160: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.12:53160
2019-04-29 10:05:01.505 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 042 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.6:58990 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer0.org6.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=12m13.9399713s
2019-04-29 10:06:01.851 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 043 TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.12:56774: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.12:56774
2019-04-29 10:06:01.255 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 044 TLS handshake failed with error read tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.16:46448: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.16:46448
2019-04-29 10:06:15.950 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 045 TLS handshake failed with error read tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.15:40150: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.15:40150
2019-04-29 10:06:35.280 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 046 TLS handshake failed with error read tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.10:58730: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.10:58730
2019-04-29 10:07:01.826 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 047 TLS handshake failed with error read tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.15:42306: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.15:42306
2019-04-29 10:07:28.959 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 048 TLS handshake failed with error read tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.15:43188: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.15:43188
2019-04-29 10:07:41.584 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 049 TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.16:50732: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.16:50732
2019-04-29 10:07:41.588 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 04a TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.10:60944: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.10:60944
2019-04-29 10:09:28.011 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 04b TLS handshake failed with error read tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.12:34104: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.12:34104
2019-04-29 10:09:35.539 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 04c TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.15:46992
2019-04-29 10:09:37.273 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 04d TLS handshake failed with error read tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.21:60784: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.21:60784
2019-04-29 10:09:51.675 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 04e streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.5:34230 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org3.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=12m36.9833739s
2019-04-29 10:10:19.391 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 04f TLS handshake failed with error read tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.10:37742: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.10:37742
2019-04-29 10:11:03.820 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 050 TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.15:49282: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.15:49282
2019-04-29 10:11:50.225 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 051 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.10:39828
2019-04-29 10:12:00.370 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 052 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.16:54714 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer0.org4.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=2m7.7656338s
2019-04-29 10:12:33.248 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 053 TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.12:40616: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.12:40616
2019-04-29 10:13:26.462 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 054 TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.15:52192: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.15:52192
2019-04-29 10:17:17.682 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 056 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.18:42402 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer0.org2.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=15m28.4743647s
2019-04-29 10:17:17.029 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 055 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.10:42422 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org5.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=3m30.3176409s
2019-04-29 10:17:18.203 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 057 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.2:34188 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org1.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=24m57.9669675s
2019-04-29 10:17:33.039 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 058 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.13:33370 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer0.org3.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=25m27.3147765s
2019-04-29 10:21:44.012 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 059 TLS handshake failed with error read tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.16:34476: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.16:34476
2019-04-29 10:21:44.274 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 05a TLS handshake failed with error read tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.10:44728: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.10:44728
2019-04-29 10:21:44.368 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 05b TLS handshake failed with error read tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.10:44880: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.10:44880
2019-04-29 10:21:42.931 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 05c TLS handshake failed with error read tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.16:34258: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.16:34258
2019-04-29 10:21:44.473 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 05d TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.10:45512
2019-04-29 10:21:44.475 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 05e TLS handshake failed with error read tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.16:34916: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.16:34916
2019-04-29 10:21:44.476 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 05f streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.17:48106 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org2.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=29m27.2417856s
2019-04-29 10:21:45.475 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 060 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.9:45620 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer0.org1.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=19m21.88722s
2019-04-29 10:21:46.154 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 061 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.18:44768
2019-04-29 10:21:46.154 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 062 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.16:35304
2019-04-29 10:21:46.155 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 063 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.16:35572
2019-04-29 10:21:46.155 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 064 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.13:56844
2019-04-29 10:21:46.155 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 065 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.13:56324
2019-04-29 10:21:46.156 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 066 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.17:44560
2019-04-29 10:21:46.156 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 067 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.17:45632
2019-04-29 10:21:46.156 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 068 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.13:55768
2019-04-29 10:21:46.157 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 069 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.18:45094
2019-04-29 10:21:46.157 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 06a TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.15:56970
2019-04-29 10:21:46.157 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 06b TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.13:55958
2019-04-29 10:21:46.158 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 06c TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.10:46386
2019-04-29 10:21:46.158 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 06d TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.13:55686
2019-04-29 10:21:46.158 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 06e TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.16:39090
2019-04-29 10:21:46.159 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 06f TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.18:44914
2019-04-29 10:21:46.159 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 070 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.18:45502
2019-04-29 10:22:54.975 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 071 TLS handshake failed with error read tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.12:50832: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.12:50832
2019-04-29 10:24:41.907 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 072 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.12:52800
2019-04-29 10:24:40.408 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 073 TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.9:52108: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.9:52108
2019-04-29 10:25:46.809 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 074 TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.16:42928: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.16:42928
2019-04-29 10:26:57.614 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 076 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.17:47104 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org2.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=4m14.3823991s
2019-04-29 10:26:57.614 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 077 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.13:60228 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer0.org3.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=4m22.7790836s
2019-04-29 10:26:58.508 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 078 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.10:50802 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer1.org5.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=4m20.5293458s
2019-04-29 10:26:56.949 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 075 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.18:49420 grpc.peer_subject="CN=peer0.org2.example.com,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error="context finished before block retrieved: context canceled" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=4m21.859575s
2019-04-29 10:27:01.671 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 079 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.13:36976
2019-04-29 10:27:01.672 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 07a TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.18:54622
2019-04-29 10:27:01.673 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 07b TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.17:52116
2019-04-29 10:27:01.673 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 07c TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.10:55420
2019-04-29 10:27:01.674 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 07d TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.13:37372
2019-04-29 10:27:01.713 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 07e TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.18:54796
2019-04-29 10:27:01.714 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 07f TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.17:52318: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.17:52318
2019-04-29 10:27:01.714 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 080 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.16:45102
2019-04-29 10:27:01.715 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 081 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.13:37594
2019-04-29 10:27:01.715 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 082 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.10:55758
2019-04-29 10:27:01.715 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 083 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.15:37494
2019-04-29 10:27:01.719 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 084 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.18:54992
2019-04-29 10:27:01.726 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 085 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.13:36702
2019-04-29 10:27:01.774 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 086 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.10:55970
2019-04-29 10:27:06.824 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 087 TLS handshake failed with error write tcp 172.18.0.4:7050->172.18.0.10:56316: i/o timeout server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.18.0.10:56316
```

This is peer logs.

[image]

Can someone help me to solve this problem? I tried a lot to find out a solution to this problem. But I was unable to find out a solution to this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have lots of TLS errors in your Peer log and your Orderer log.  I would suggest testing without TLS on all the services within the docker-compose.yaml file.  This might fix the problem, but it will certainly make the logs easier to read.  If it fixes the problem you will know exactly what the problem is.

If you still have problems with connectivity with the Orderer, then try these docker commands to see what docker networking bridges you have, and what containers are using those networks:

`docker network list` and `docker inspect <bridge-name>`

For testing and development it is easiest to have all the containers running on the same docker network bridge.

**Additional Information (answer edited)**

The "instantiate" command generates a temporary container (with a random name) used to Build the "Chaincode Container".  So "determined_archimedes" might be that temporary container or it might just be a test container you created in the past - you can check what Image the container is based on by looking at `docker ps -a` or looking at the log and you should be able to see if it is a Fabric container or some other 'test' container.

The network bridge used by the Chaincode Container (and I think the temporary container) is determined by the Environment Variable `CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE` - you should check that all your peers in the docker-compose.yaml file have this set to the same value as the networking bridge with the other fabric components.

Comment: I disable the tls then tls errors are removed but the error in the same state. All the containers are running on the same bridge except "determined_archimedes"

Comment: Yeah. That is the tempory container created by Instantiate command.

Comment: Environment Variable `CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE` does not change chaincode container bridge

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the peer logs, the peer can't see the orderer, error 623. Check how do you have the network and if you can connect from one to the other. Are you using composer? If so, are they in the same network?

Comment: I am not using the composer with this project. I am new to this Hyperledger fabric so can you please tell me how to connect from one to the other.